# How would I sort a vector of structs by value?

Tags: clojure

More specifically: how would I sort a vector of structs by the value of a certain key?

For instance, if I had:

```
(defstruct Item :weight :value :cost
(def my-items [(struct Item 30 50 5)
               (struct Item 15 75 20)
               (struct Item 50 10 35)])
```

How would I sort all of the items in the vector by, let's say, value?

Comment: You should probably look into using [`defrecord`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/defrecord) instead. From _The Joy of Clojure_ p.190: "With the advent of `defrecord`, the need for structs has been nearly eliminated, and therefore structs aren’t covered in this book."

Comment: Coincidentally enough, I've already switched over to defrecord.  Thanks though!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [sort-by](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/sort-by)

```
Clojure 1.4.0
user=> (defstruct Item :weight :value :cost)
#'user/Item
user=> (def my-items [(struct Item 30 50 5)
               (struct Item 15 75 20)
               (struct Item 50 10 35)])
#'user/my-items
user=> (sort-by :value my-items)
({:weight 50, :value 10, :cost 35} {:weight 30, :value 50, :cost 5} {:weight 15, :value 75, :cost 20})
```

Comment: I was severely over-complicating this.  Thank you!